# Wiki with line-based history like "annotate" in version control software

Tags: web-apps, wiki, annotation, history

I am searching for a wiki software which supports line-based history like the version control feature "annotate/blame".

Per line, I want to know:

- who changed it
- modification date and time
- other changes made with this page save

The wiki should be used via browser and usable for non-geek people :-)